# Data not insert into codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, sql-insert

I will try to insert & also update data using session in Codeigniter, but data not inserted into the database even its print save successfully.
Here is my controller:

```
   public function save($user_id)
   {
   $this->load->model('Users');
   $code=$this->input->post('code');
   $name=$this->input->post('name');
   $address=$this->input->post('address');

  $user_data= array(
    'code' =>$code,
   'name'=>$name,
 'address'=>$address,
 'active'=>1
    );
        if($this->Users->save($user_data,$user_id))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"save sucesss");
        }else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"not save");
        }
        redirect('home');
}
```

& this is my model:

```
 public function save($data,$id)
 {
 if (id=='') {
  // code...
  $this->db->insert('user',$data);
  return true;
}else
{
  $this->db->where('id',$id)
  ->update('user',$data);
  return true;
}
return false;
  }
```

Data insert if I removed if in model!

Comment: I'm sure it's a typo, but `if(id=='')` should be `if($id=='')`  Missing $ in front of `id`

Comment: Do the table columns `code`, `name` and `address` all allow NULL values?

Comment: Is the value of `$user_id` (to the `save()` method) a field on the form?

Comment: actually I try this from youtube, so I don't know all ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the model always returning true no matter the outcome of the database operation. You should use the return value from `insert()` or `update()` so the "message" reports what actually happens.

Note that the argument to `save` has a default value. Now you can call the save URL without an argument and it will automatically do an insert.

```
public function save($user_id = NULL)
{
    $this->load->model('users');
    $user_data = array(
        'code' => $this->input->post('code'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'active' => 1
    );

    if($this->Users->save($user_data, $user_id))
    {
        $msg = "save sucesss";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "not save";
    }

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg);
    redirect('home');
}

public function save($data, $id)
{
    if(empty($id))
    {
        // code...
        // insert returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure
        return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    }

    // update() accepts a third argument, a "where" array
    // and returns TRUE on success, FALSE on failure
    return $this->db->update('user', $data, array('id' => $id));
}
```

Now have an accurate report on the database operations.

Comment: why you are working so hard, even that sagar not response even you have comment was wright

Comment: Ha ha, So when Sagar returns maybe he will learn a new trick or two.

Comment: sorry, I will more active next time & thanks, its working now

Answer (score 1):

the first check is data is coming in **save controller or not** if it's not getting the data then fix it. If coming then pass it in a model in the correct format and it will definitely be inserted in the database.

> use following printing data

```
echo $data;
var_dump($data);
print($data);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to rename your model calling eg:

```
$this->load->model('users');
```

and use this to call your method:

```
$this->users->save($user_data,$user_id)
```

your model should look like this then:

```
public function save($data, $id) {
    if ($id) {
        $this->db->where('id', $id)
                ->update('user', $data);
        return true;
    }
    $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    return true;
}
```

if you want to use your flashdata on the next request, use this:

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
$this->session->keep_flashdata(array('item1', 'item2', 'item3'));
```

because flashdata is only for the next request:

> CodeIgniter supports “flashdata”, or session data that will only be available for the next request, and is then automatically cleared.

Comment: I put $user_id='null' in controller but its still not working

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR  where you get your user_id?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR normally if you give a propertie to controller, you do it through get in your routing https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routing